# Dynamic Name to the Control Template in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, prism

We need to assign the Name property at the runtime using the data binding. We have the control template defined and `WPF` doesn't allow to bind the name from the the Data Bind object.

If I do, I get error like,

> Error 3   MarkupExtensions are not
>   allowed for Uid or Name property
>   values, so '{Binding Name}' is not
>   valid. Line 15 Position
>   36.   C:\Users\gsubramani\Workspace\ProLinkIII_Experiment\BasicFrame\Resources\TreeTemplate.xaml  15  36  BasicFrame

To work around, Is it possible to define a custom property which intern set the Name property of the control through data binding?

I don't know how to the handle the `DependencyProperty` in `WPF` so that I can define a custom property that intern set the Name property of the control? ( I am very new to WPF world).

Comment: Why would you like to bind with the name property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to define an attached dependency as per the documentation here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc903943%28VS.95%29.aspx

Then provide a method which is invoked when this property changes. You can do this by adding another argument to the propertyMetdata, that points to a static method:

```
private static void OnMyNamePropertyChanged(DependencyObject d,
    DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // d is the object which the attached property has been set on
}
```

In this handler, d, is the object that the property has been attached to, and e.NewValue will contain the name.

However, I think it is a little odd that you want to bind the Name of your elements. Can you please share why you want to do this?

Regards, Colin E.

Comment: Don't know about the OP, but we need it because UI Automation Framework works based on Name property, so we want to set the name of an element, and since it is in a template, we would like to use binding.

Answer (score 3):

If you need this for UI Automation, I'd recommend using the solution described here:
http://www.jonathanantoine.com/2011/11/03/coded-ui-tests-automationid-or-how-to-find-the-chose-one-control/

You can use the AutomationProperties.AutomationId with binding in WPF, and you can use this value as automationid in your UI Automation client.